# counter example of inverse function theorem

Tags: calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Prove that in the inverse function theorem, the hypothesis that $f$ is $C^1$ cannot be weakened to the hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable. I read an example of my teacher, but I can't have any analysis argument for the fact that $f$ is not one to one in any neighborhood of $0$. Here it is,

$$f(0)=0, \qquad f(x)=x + 2x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}, x\neq 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Except at $0$, the function is $C^1$, so you can analyse it by examining its derivate on the interval $(0,\varepsilon)$. If $f$ was injective on $(0,\varepsilon)$, then it would have to be monotone and hence its derivative could not have a change of sign there. Show that it does.

*Note:* I had originally and erroneously looked at the function $f(x)=x + x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$, which is harder to analyse, and I analysed it sloppily and wrongly.

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb question, but why isn't it $C^1$ around $0$?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at $0$ (indeed $f'(0)=1$), but $f'$ is not continuous at $0$. Looking at $f'$ in a neighbourhood of $0$ is exactly what one has to do.

Comment: I found the link below, the answer is so clearly:  http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=7QqickY0yh8C&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=counter+example+for+inverse+function+theorem&source=bl&ots=Ubynm_BRBu&sig=3wj1xV9c8tmkdrzZhlufKqWXOo8&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=ZzcHU6HxKYO8oQSQ0oHwAQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I had missed a $2$ in the function, I will modify my answer.

Comment: Why when $f$ has both local maxima and minima arbitrarily close to zero, it cannot be inverted around the origin ?

Comment: @Chloe.Sannon, I am not sure what prompts that question, but a continuous function around a local extremum is not injective.

Comment: The second paragraph of your answer is wrong. The function $f(x)=x+x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is not bijective in any nbhd of $0$.

Comment: @ZFR, I think you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The upper and lower bounds for the function tell us that $0<y=f(x)$ may have solutions between the positive solutions of

$y=x\pm2x^2=2(x\pm\tfrac14)^2-\tfrac18$ or $x=\tfrac14(\sqrt{1+8y}\mp1)$.

This segment of length $\tfrac12$ at height $y$ is long enough for multiple oscillations of the $\sin(\frac1x)$ factor, especially if $y$ and thus the lower bound for $x$ is close to zero. So however close to $0$ one restricts the interval under consideration, there is always a value of $y$ small enough to get the left bound close enough to zero to have multiple oscillations cross over the line at height $y$.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that your teacher is wrong. Look here  for a version of the inverse function theorem when the function is only everywhere differentiable but not $C^1$ (see for example [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75049/does-the-inverse-function-theorem-hold-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps)).